# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TAB LESPACE, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

I’m using Django 1.9.1 with Python 3.5.2 and I'm having a problem running a Python script that uses Django models.

```
C:\Users\admin\trailers>python load_from_api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_from_api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from movies.models import Movie
  File "C:\Users\admin\trailers\movies\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Genre(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\admin\trailers\movies\models.py", line 6, in Genre
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init_
_.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init_
_.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TAB
LESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment
 variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing s
ettings.
```

here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "trailers.settings")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "trailers.settings"
import django
django.setup()
import tmdbsimple as tmdb
from movies.models import Movie

#some code...
```

I can't really figure out what's wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to run it without changing the script and that's by using

`python manag.py shell`

and then

`exec(open('filename').read())`

that seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Django Custom Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) - they are really simple to use, they use your settings, your environment, you can pass parameters and also you can write help strings so you can use `--help`

Then you just call it with `./manage.py my_custom_command`

Or if you just want to run your script add this to the your script

```
project_path = '/home/to/your/trailers/project/src'
if project_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(project_path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "trailers.common")

import django
django.setup()
```